# X11 DestroyNotify event returns wrong window parameter

Tags: c++, x11, xcb

I'm currently working on writing a reparenting window manager using C++ and the XCB library. I unmanage windows when I recieve an UnmapNotify event; in this case the code is very simple:

```cpp
  if (unmap_ignore > 0) {
    unmap_ignore--;
    return;
  }
  client *cl = nullptr;
  size_t idx = 0;
  for (client &c : clients) {
    if (c.window == ev->window) {
      cl = &c;
      break;
    }
    idx++;
  }
  if (!cl)
    return;
  xcb_unmap_window(conn, cl->frame);
  clients.erase(clients.begin() + idx);
```

However, this does not work for some clients that don't bother unmapping the window (usually happens when you force kill the process). Then instead a DestroyNotify is sent. However the `ev->window` field there (typeof ev = xcb_destroy_notify_event_t) is some value that isn't what I want... here are some example logs (also note each line is a new DestroyNotify event, I get it twice for some reason and each time the #window field is different but not correct):

```
Found a client window: 4194307 but this was destroyed: 4194305
Found a client window: 4194307 but this was destroyed: 4194313
```

I remember before I tried to write a window manager in Xlib and had this exact same issue. I must be missing something obvious though, but if I look at the code of other reparenting window managers like Awesome or Herbsluftwm they just use the window field and have no problems. What am I doing wrong?

(my full code is here: http://ix.io/3yDj)

One thing I suspect is that it is just giving me two children windows of the destroyed parent instead of sending the actual parent. no idea why, but it is the most logical thing I can come up with. I just want to be able to handle this so I can unmap the frame for things that don't send UnmapNotify events.

I also first thought that it may report DestroyNotify on the parent window instead of the client reparented one, so I tried checking the frame but to no avail:

```
Found a client window: 2097152 but this was destroyed: 4194305
Found a client window: 2097152 but this was destroyed: 4194313
```

I've been truly stumped on this so any help is appreciated, thanks!

Awesome for example does the exact same thing as I tried with ev->window:

```c
static void
event_handle_destroynotify(xcb_destroy_notify_event_t *ev)
{
    client_t *c;

    if((c = client_getbywin(ev->window)))
        client_unmanage(c, CLIENT_UNMANAGE_DESTROYED);
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < globalconf.embedded.len; i++)
            if(globalconf.embedded.tab[i].win == ev->window)
            {
                xembed_window_array_take(&globalconf.embedded, i);
                luaA_systray_invalidate();
            }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting StructureNotifyMask or SubstructureNotifyMask or both, and on which window?

Comment: I set SubstructureNotifyMask and SubstructureRedirect mask (`XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY | XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT`) on the root window.

Comment: SubstructureNotifyMask should cause the root window to get DestroyNotify events on its children. What is your reparenting structure? Do you have each window reparented to its own parent or to the root?

Comment: I do get destroynotify events; just the window field of them is not the actual destroyed window. I have each window reparented to a frame window I create, you can see it in `window_manager::handle_map_request` in my code.

Comment: Perhaps a workaround might be to try to get the parent window of these that DestroyNotify is reported for if they are actually children windows. But I'm not sure that is possible, even, with an already destroyed window...

Comment: Which window do you expect to appear there? The actual client window is a child of a frame window which is a child of the root window. The root should get DestroyNotify when the frame is destroyed, and the frame should get DestroyNotify when the client is destroyed (but you don't set SubstructureNotifyMask on the frame). I see spurious ConfigureNotify/DestroyNotify pairs in my experiments, I am not quite sure why they are sent, but they are due to StructureNotifyMask, not SubstructureNotifyMask, and ev->window == ev->event. Your root should not get the event when its *grandchild* is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful! Setting XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY | XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT on the frame window solves my issue, and now I do understand why. (Might want to post that as an answer.)